# Фрагменты  андроид

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток  господа
Есть  фрагмент:

```
public class Launcher extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    static final Uri URI_TOOL = Uri.parse("content://ru.htsprovider.htspdata/dataplasma");
    static final Uri URI_DATA = Uri.parse("content://ru.htsprovider.htspdata/datatable");

    static final String PARAMETR_NAME_PLASMA = "parameter_name_plasma";
    static final String STRAIGHT_CUT = "straight_cut";
    static final String OBLIQUE_CUT_TOP = "oblique_cut_top";
    static final String OBLIQUE_CUT_LOWER = "oblique_cut_lower";
    static final String MARKING = "marcing";
    static final String PUNCHING = "punching";
    static final String QUALITY_HOLE = "quality_hole";

    LauncherToolAdapter adapter;  //Адаптер
    android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager;
    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCallbacks;
    ListView lvTool;
    ListView lvData;
    TextView textView;

    public Launcher() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] from = new String[] { PARAMETR_NAME_PLASMA, STRAIGHT_CUT,  OBLIQUE_CUT_TOP, OBLIQUE_CUT_LOWER, MARKING, PUNCHING, QUALITY_HOLE};
        adapter = new LauncherToolAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_tool, null, from, null);
        lvTool = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvLauncherTool);
        lvTool.setAdapter(adapter);

        mCallbacks = this;
        loaderManager = getActivity().getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, mCallbacks);
        //loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, mCallbacks);

        View rootViewLauncher = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_launcher, container, false);
                return rootViewLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), URI_TOOL, null, null, null, null);
            break;
        case 1:
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), URI_DATA, null, null, null, null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
        case 0:
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            break;
        case 1:
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
        case 0:
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
            break;
        case 1:
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
Фрагмент  подключаю  через  разметку:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag"
        android:name="ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.PlaceholderFragment"
        android:layout_width="127pt"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/item" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_launcher"
        android:name="ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.Launcher"
        android:layout_width="490pt"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/item_tool" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>

Разметка  фрагмента:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lvLauncherTool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Выдает  портянку:

```
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav/ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     ... 11 more
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.Launcher.onCreateView(Launcher.java:49)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4664)
05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
```

В  чем  моя  криворукость?

Заранее  спасибо)

Comment: ошибка nullPointerException здесь:

    ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)

код, который вы привели, ничем не поможет.

Comment: В  логе  

    E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 05-14 13:44:07.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): at ru.systemtehnolodgi.stav.Launcher.onCreateView(Launcher.java:49)

указывает  на  строку:

    lvTool.setAdapter(adapter);
Может тут  проблема?

Comment: @alexmx, постарайтесь подбирать более информативные заголовки для своих вопросов

Comment: слишком много букаф в топике. лень читать

Comment: давайте  начнем  с  малого. У  меня  на  данный  момент  адаптер  требует  колонку  _id  у  меня  она  названна  по  другому plasma_id
Это  каким  то  образом  влияет????

Comment: Посмотрите повнимательнее в каком View вы ищете ListView. Может быть нужно его искать во view фрагмента?

Answer (score 1):

> давайте начнем с малого. У меня на данный момент адаптер требует колонку _id у меня она названна по другому plasma_id Это каким то образом влияет????

Да  влияет